# Apollo/GraphQL Mutation Works in GraphIQL, but Not in Client Code?

Tags: graphql, apollostack

I have this mutation working correctly in GraphIQL at http://localhost:8080/graphiql:

**QUERY**

```
mutation($fromID: String!, $toID: String!, $msgText: String!){
  createIM(fromID: $fromID, toID: $toID, msgText: $msgText){
    fromID
    toID
    msgText
  }
}
```

**...AND QUERY VARIABLES**

```
{
  "fromID": "1",
  "toID": "2",
  "msgText": "Test from GraphIQL #3. It's working!!!"
}
```

Now I need to implement this in code.

**CLIENT CODE**

```
sendInstantMsg(){
    const {textToSend} = this.refs;
    const {toID} = this.props;

    const fromID = Meteor.userId();
    const msgText = trimInput(textToSend.getValue());

    client.query({
        query: gql`
            query mutation($fromID: String!, $toID: String!, $msgText: String!){
                createIM(fromID: $fromID, toID: $toID, msgText: $msgText){
                    fromID
                    toID
                    msgText
                }
            }
        `,
        variables: {
            fromID: fromID,
            toID: toID,
            msgText: msgText
        },
        forceFetch: false,
    }).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log('got data', data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('there was an error sending the query', error);
    });
}
```

The query variables (fromID, toID, and msgText) come in to the function as expected, but Apollo throws an error:

`message: "Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"`

What am I missing?

Comment: Look in the chrome network tab - can you see the request in there? What URL does it hit, and what is the return value?

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:3000/graphql. Referer:http://localhost:3000/create_im/572bddac4ecbbac0ffe37fdf. Request Payload: {"query":"query mutation($fromID: String!, $toID: String!, $msgText: String!) {\n  createIM(fromID: $fromID, toID: $toID, msgText: $msgText) {\n    fromID\n    toID\n    msgText\n  }\n}\n","variables":{"fromID":"s9trFBxQcpaCjnon2","toID":"572bddac4ecbbac0ffe37fdf","msgText":"Testing 123"},"operationName":"mutation"}. Where can I find the return value?

Comment: In the file containing the quoted code, I access ApolloClient via `import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'; const client = new ApolloClient();`. Is that enough to gain access to the previously defined resolvers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this instead..
you should use mutate for mutations not query..

```
client.mutate({
            mutation: gql`
                mutation createIM($fromID: String!, $toID: String!, $msgText: String!){
                    createIM(fromID: $fromID, toID: $toID, msgText: $msgText){
                        fromID
                        toID
                        msgText
                    }
                }
            `,
            variables: {
                fromID: fromID,
                toID: toID,
                msgText: msgText
            },
            forceFetch: false,
        }).then(({ data }) => {
```